# Is there a more efficient way of annotating a field than SerializerMethodField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code which annotates the `Item.name` that the `ItemSale` represents. It works and all but a GET on this view could call upwards of 200 `ItemSale` objects which, if I understand correctly, would also mean 200 queries just to get each `ItemSales`'s `Item.name`? If so, I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing this, if any.

ItemSale Serializer:

```
class ItemSaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.ItemSale
        fields = ['quantity', 'price', 'item_name']

    def get_item_name(self, obj):
        return obj.item.name
```

Sale Serializer:

```
class SaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_sales = ItemSaleSerializer(many=True, source='itemsale_set')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Sale
        fields = ('id', 'uid', 'dt_date', 'total', 'item_sales')
```

I tried creating a custom manager for `ItemSale` and annotating the extra field through `all()` however it doesn't seem to get called since in this case, the list of `ItemSale`s is being nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to provide queryset with prefetched data, so in your view it would be for example:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return ItemSale.objects.select_related('item')
```

This will make a JOIN to Item table and fetch all the results in one query.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `charField` for `item_name` and pass `'item.name'` as source.

Comment: Hey Shubham, this still has the unintended side effect of causing multiple queries in the background so I ended up going with marxin's answer. Thank you for the suggestion though!